# Windows Search does not find files by name

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-search

I'm facing some really sublime issue with windows search index right now and really hope that someone here has a hint on how to troubleshoot, since I can not find any approaches on how to fix windows search besides rebuilding the index, which I've done several times now.

*The occuring misbehaviour:*

- browsing any share, no matter if it has hundreds of subfolders or just ten plain files in them, **windows search does not find files by name.**

  - Example: I'm in a share that only has a few files in it. I copy a files name and paste it into explorers search pane - and I do not get any search results
- the contents of any files, e.g. OCR'd PDF or TXT, get indexed properly - and get returned by windows search.

*Affected setup:*

- Fileserver on Windows Server 2012R2 running on a ESXi 5.5 Cluster
- ~5TB net storage available on ~30 shares, ~3M files total
- Every share is affected - from every client. I do only have Windows 7 machines running in this environment, but a test from a W8.1 machine gave me the same results.

*Things I've tried*

- completely deleted and rebuild the index several times
- excluded all hidden shares, e.g. my deployment share, from the index
- played a bit with Windows Search Syntax - e.g. searching for `filename:myfile.txt` or `name:myfile.txt`
- changed indexing behaviour for test purposes for pdf files: `Index properties only` instead of `Index Properties and File Contents`

I'd really appreciate any tips on how to progress - this problem is becoming a real pain for our staff.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you've looked into this in some detail, but just in case; does this behaviour still occur when using the `name:` prefix to search for filenames only?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for your comment, I have indeed tried that - I'll update the original question.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with how the index is used in Windows 10; "Classic Start Menu" will happily find "template-timetable-weeklist.ods" if I search for "weeklist", as it would have been the case in Windows 7. The normal start menu finds the same file only if I type "tempate-timetable" but not if I type "weeklist", even though both access the same search index.