# Make windows 10 file search match whole filename instead of just beginning?

Tags: windows-10, search, search-indexing

Is it possible to do document searches by whole filename from the Windows 10 Start menu, without having to open an app?

Up until Windows 8 this was possible and, through Classic Start Menu, remains my preferred way of opening documents.

### Observations

Up until Windows 8, the index search integrated with the Start Menu would by match files by whole name. E.g. given the file

```
E:\Dropbox\lib\templates\template-timetable-wochenliste-workday.ods
```

typing `wochenliste` into the start menu would show this document among the results. Typing `ochenliste` however would not give results, i.e. the combination of indexing and query effectively did a "contains word starting with ..." query.

In Windows 10 (currently winver 1903), typing `wochenliste` no longer finds the document, but typing `template-` does, i.e. it seems Windows 10 matches with a "starts with" instead of a "contains" filter. This is especially curious, because [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/) will still find the document, even though it uses the same underlying index, i.e. there must be some change in how a search query is constructed from the start-menu search box.

Furthermore, the search box no longer supports operator search like `name:~*.pdf`.

Using the "documents:" filter (corresponding to choosing the "documents" tab of start menu search) doesn't change anything except for excluding web results.

### Related questions

Unanswered related questions exist (e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/937804/windows-search-does-not-find-files-by-name)) but don't pinpoint the issue to a change in querying behavior.

Correspondingly, the answers, if any, neither solve the issue nor comment on whether a solution is possible. Instead they offer workarounds in the form of third-party software.

### Existing workarounds

For more traditional search results, I currently use [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/). However, using the native start menu and classic shell in parallel is somewhat jarring, and I'd rather find a fix for the native start menu.

Comment: The nature of search changed in the later upgrades of Windows 10 so that Search can look for more things in more places and defaults to All. The current version of Windows is V1909 - soon to be V2004. So a different approach is to use Search and then indicate where you wish to Search - often Documents for me.

Comment: @John That doesn't change the behavior of providing incomplete results by querying the index overly specifically in the background. Where in Windows 7, 8, 8.1 I'd type `wochenliste <ENTER>` to open the file, I now have to type out the beginning of the filename, which I may not have memorized (especially for files which have date-based names).

Comment: Does putting a `*` first when searching work for you (i.e `*wochenliste` rather than `wochenliste`)?  This works for me on version 2004 (as does `*.pdf` or `documents: *.pdf` but not `name: *.pdf`)

Comment: @lx07 No it doesn't.Could be then, that it was changed again? I have set to not instantly install new updates, so not having 2004 yet is expected, but I'll have to look into why 1909 has never been installed.